# Keep getting 'unused argument' error when trying to produce a qqplot in R

Tags: r, plot, simulation, probability

```
library(GoFKernel)
library(ggplot2)

rejection_fx_sqz <- function(n){
  x <- vector()  # the output vector in which simulated values should be stored
  acpt <- 0 # count the accepted values
  tol <- 0 # count the total number of values (accepted or not accepted)
  len_x = 0
  while(len_x < n){
    n_to_gen = max((n-len_x)/0.69,20) # determine number to generate - not less than 20
    tol = tol + n_to_gen # count the total number of values simulated
    u1 = runif(n_to_gen) # simulate u1
    u2 = runif(n_to_gen) # simulate u2
    y = inv_G(u2)

    g <- g_x(y)
    d <- g*y*(5-y)
    condU <- (M*u1) >= 1/d
    condL <- !condU
    condL[condL] <- (M*u1[condL]) <= lower(y[condL])/d[condL]
    other <- !(condU | condL) # condition of below the W_U and above W_L
    # modify condL because some samples can still be accepted given condL is false
    condL[other] <- u1[other] <= fstar(y[other])/(M*g[other]) 
    cond <- condL

    acpt = acpt + sum(cond) # count the number of accepted values
    x <- c(x, y[cond]) # add accepted values to the output vector
    len_x <- length(x)
  }
  p = acpt / tol
  return(list(x=x[1:n], p=p))
}

n=100000
x=rejection_fx_sqz(n) # a function that simulates from f(x) by generating n samples
x_fx <- data.frame(x=x$x)
x=x_fx$x
x_plot = cbind(x_fx, fy = 1/(I*x*(5-x))*exp(-1/8*(-1+log(x/(5-x)))^2)) 

f_cdf <- function(x) {
  integrate(fstar, 0, x)$value/I
}

# quantile function, inverse cdf
f_q <- inverse(f_cdf, lower=0.000000000000000001, upper=4.999999999999999999)

ggplot(x_plot, aes(sample=x))+
  labs(title="Empirical against theoretical quantiles")+
   stat_qq(distribution=f_q) +
   stat_qq_line(distribution=f_q)
```

What I'm trying to do is to produce a 'quantile-quantile' diagnostic plot for my algorithm for simulating from f(x). The problem is that I keep getting two error messages which says:

Computation failed in `stat_qq()`: unused argument (p = quantiles)
Computation failed in `stat_qq_line()`: unused argument (p = quantiles)

I am beginner for r-language and this is driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your example code is incomplete:  we don't have `rejection_fx_sqz`.  Please simplify the code as much as possible so that we can run it but it still gives the same error.

Comment: @user2554330 I'm sorry but I think it would make the code even more complex if I attach the details of the function. This function is simulating from f(x) by using a rejection sampling algorithm which is modified by pretesting-squeezing. It is very long function and I think it's unrelated to the 'plotting' part which I have problems with. However, I still add the function as you required.

Comment: You missed the point.  Your code still won't run; now it's because you didn't give us `inv_G`.  You need to **simplify** your code:  drop everything that isn't relevant to the error you saw.  Then check that it is **reproducible**:  make sure it is self-contained and you can run it in a empty R session.  The `reprex` package makes this easy:  just copy your code into the clipboard, and see if `reprex::reprex()` shows your error.